# Sync Adapter in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I had to create a functionality of syncing data between client and server after every 2 mins of interval, i had gone through many link and finally decided to work with sync adapter, but problem is i have found the samples which are in Android Native and finding difficulty to implement in Xamarin Android,
If any one can help me with reference link or Code, It would be helpful. 
Also suggest me if there is some other way to achieve the above requirement.

I have Tried to Replicate the code in Xamarin Android but on debug i am getting following error

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.codexpedia.syncadapter.MyContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.codexpedia.syncadapter.MyContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.codexpedia.syncadapter-Zlc889tOOvYUlCYXRU5pMw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.codexpedia.syncadapter-Zlc889tOOvYUlCYXRU5pMw==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.codexpedia.syncadapter-Zlc889tOOvYUlCYXRU5pMw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

[image: Here is Mine File & Folder Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file gets generated on build. Hence, you should be careful what you put in it. Instead of adding your `ContentProvider` to the manifest yourself, you should do this through attributes on your class instead.

```
[ContentProvider(new string[] { MyContentProvider.AUTHORITY })]
public class MyContentProvider : ContentProvider
{
    public const string AUTHORITY = "com.company.sample.MyContentProvider";
    ...
}
```

This will automatically generate the appropriate sections in the manifest.

You can read more about ContentProviders and how to set these up in the Xamarin Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/content-providers/

Comment: tried this it worked at some extent, but still facing problem my Service Class OnCreate Method is not Getting Fired.